# Magento2 eslint entire custom code

Tags: magento2, javascript, grunt

I've noticed Magento2 has [Javascript Coding Standards](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/code-standard-javascript.html), in which they reference an [eslint config file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Js/_files/eslint/.eslintrc-magento).

Suppose I have an M2 project I'm developing with a large group of folks and I'd like the team to adhere to these standards. How can I leverage this? For example, do I need to make a custom `grunt` task, or is there one already present somewhere?

Ideally I'd like something like `grunt eslint` that would look over all the javascript files in the custom theme and extensions.